# OS X 10.10 default username and password?

Tags: macos, password, osx-server, ssh, apple-remote-desktop

Is there a default username/password for brand new OS X installs that have yet to go through the initial setup process?

I have several headless macs already racked, but no display set up for them, because we intend to run them through ARD (Apple Remote Desktop) and ssh.

Before the initial setup (where the .AppleSetupDone file gets created for the first time), is there a default username and password for either remote desktop or ssh?